# Crystal Reports in ASP.NET - Some Work, Some Don't

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have 4 similar Crystal Reports made. When I set the report name to the CrystalReportSource (using the drop down, so I know it's spelled correctly), only 2 of them will give me a little preview, while the other 2 show nothing but the CrstalReportViewer control.
The same 2 reports show a blank report (nothing but the toolbar) when I run the web app.
All 4 reports display correctly in the report designer.
I've looked through every property I can think of, but don't see any difference between the ones that work, and the ones that don't.

Maybe someone can give me a better idea of where to look.

In case it makes a difference, 3 of the reports were clones off of the previous report with the database location changed.

Again, they all work in the designer.

Any ideas? :-)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/AFRA.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ReportViewer.aspx.vb" Inherits="ReportViewer" %>
<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="main" Runat="Server">
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
    AutoDataBind="true" DisplayGroupTree="False" Height="50px" 
        ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
        <Report FileName="RPT\StatsRevenue.rpt">
        </Report>
    </CR:CrystalReportSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: When do you set the ReportName to the ReportSource? You should try to change (for debug reason) in Page_Init

Comment: The default page is set in the markup. I also have code that changes it that changes it in the page_init to different reports depending on the query string.
Same results. 2 work, 2 don't. No error, just a blank report.

Comment: Did you look at the page HTML? Is there some hidden text that reports an Error text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally just figured that those 2 reports were probably just corrupt. Since they were modified reports of clones of working reports, it only took me about an hour to just make new ones from scratch.